# Get Object from other class file

Tags: java

Having issue of getting object from other class file...

This function let us take in the title (from movie class) and name (from theatre class).
2 input from user asking what is the title and name, from there we need to take in an movie object and theatre object to check is the title can be found in the movie class. same to name in theatre class.

```
public MovieScreening(Movie movieObject,Theatre theatreObject){
    this.movieObject = movieObject;
    this.theatreObject = theatreObject;
}

public Movie getMovieObject() {
    return movieObject;
}

public Theatre getTheatreObject() {
    return theatreObject;
}
```

Comment: You don't get objects from class files.

Comment: yeah i know.. but i dont know how the get the "getName" and "getTitle"

Comment: what do you mean by 'how the get the  getName and getTitle'

Comment: basically i dont know how to write out the function of the unknown line in the above code.. user will have to input for name and title. from there i have to check is the title which user key in is the same as the title in my movie list and the name of the user input must be the smae as the theatre list. then i can create a list in screeninglist.

Comment: how MovieScreening looks like?

Comment: public class MovieScreening {

Comment: how can you get objects from class file??????? the code that you have shared is not at all giving a clear view of what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong and incomplete, so I can barely have an idea of what do you want here.

But maybe, this code below can help you somehow. Please state better questions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Screener {

    private static ArrayList <MovieScreening> screenings = new ArrayList <MovieScreening>();


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String movie = "Titanic";
        String theatre = "Cineplex";

        screenings.add(new MovieScreening(new Movie("Titanic"),new Theatre("Odeon")));
        screenings.add(new MovieScreening(new Movie("run lola run"),new Theatre("Cineplex")));
        screenings.add(new MovieScreening(new Movie("Titanic"),new Theatre("Cineplex")));

        for(MovieScreening s:screenings){
            if(s.contains(movie,theatre)){
                System.out.println("Added successfully:"+s);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found:"+s);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MovieScreening {
    private Movie movie;
    private Theatre theatre;
    public MovieScreening(Movie movie, Theatre theatre) {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.theatre = theatre;
    }
    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }
    public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }
    public Theatre getTheatre() {
        return theatre;
    }
    public void setTheatre(Theatre theatre) {
        this.theatre = theatre;
    }
    public boolean contains(String movie, String theatre) {
        return this.movie.getTitle().equals(movie) && this.theatre.getName().equals(theatre);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MovieScreening [movie=" + movie + ", theatre=" + theatre + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Theatre {
    private String name;

    public Theatre(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Theatre [name=" + name + "]";
    }


}
```

and

```
public class Movie {
    private String title;

    public Movie(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [title=" + title + "]";
    }


}
```

will probably give you an output like this

```
 Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found:MovieScreening [movie=Movie [title=Titanic], theatre=Theatre [name=Odeon]]
 Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found:MovieScreening [movie=Movie [title=run lola run], theatre=Theatre [name=Cineplex]]
 Added successfully:MovieScreening [movie=Movie [title=Titanic], theatre=Theatre [name=Cineplex]]
```